# "Add as Link" for JavaScript files returning 404 in debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Using a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.net web application, I have several projects that share some JavaScript/css files. The most logical way for them to share these files is to place the files in a single folder and each project has them included with the "Add as Link" option. However, if I add the files this way when I'm debugging using either the Visual Studio Development server or debugging using a local IIS web server all requests for these files return 404 Not Found errors. If I publish the site then the files are copied but that obviously doesn't help with debugging.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a failing on VS's part?

Answer (score 18):

To overcome this problem some time ago I created a '[MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles/)' nuget package. This package adds MsBuild target which copies all content files added as link to project folder during build.

*Note*: if you use source control then it is better to add copied files (from Web Application folder) to ignore list.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't really call that a failing, since you asked for that behavior in the first place: [linked items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jjameson/linked-files-in-visual-studio-solutions) in Visual Studio projects are actual *links* to external files. Those files can reside anywhere on the disk and are not copied into the project folder.

You might want to copy those files locally yourself during a [pre-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.100%29). That way, the files will remain synchronized and you won't duplicate them until your first compile.

Comment: Well, since I added it to the project as a link then when I request that link I should be redirected to the source instead of VS returning 404 when debugging. That is why it's a failing on VS's part to not handle a linked document correctly. I did test copying the file to the folder manually and it will return the document then but this is not something I should have to do. It defeats the purpose of a linked document to begin with.

Comment: @Matt, there's no feature (yet) to perform that kind of redirection. I suppose you could call that a shortcoming :)

Comment: That's a shame. I have a few css and js files that are shared between projects and without this feature working in all regards means duplicated code and extra steps. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the website runs right from your source folders, rather than from the bin folder. This means that the file will be missing, whether or not it is copied to the output folder.

It's probable that running from a local or remote web server would not have this problem, though I didn't get that working, and I'd rather not add IIS to my local machine if I don't have to.

Adding a pre-build copy command did work. Note that the current directory will be the bin folder. (You can use `cd` to echo the current directory to the build window if you want to see it):

If the file is in another solution, your command will look something like (three `..`s: one to get out of each of bin, project, and solution folders):

```
copy ..\..\..\OtherSolution\OtherProject\Scripts\MyJSFile.js ..\Scripts\
```

If it's in the same solution, but a different project:

```
copy ..\..\OtherProject\Scripts\MyJSFile.js ..\Scripts
```

One minor issue is that the link to the file will collide with the new copy of the file, even if you don't add it to your project. As long as you make the link first, it seems to work. If you copied the file first, you'll have to manually delete the copy, and then refresh the solution explorer before before being able to add the link.

Answer (score -2):

Select the link in Solution Explorer and then look at properties window and set Copy To Output Directory to Copy Always. Linked items are set to Do Not Copy by default.

BTW, you can copy many files as links very easily directly from Solution Explorer when using [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) extension.

Comment: The problem is the "Output Directory" is the bin folder. Copying them to the bin folder doesn't help when they need to be in the Styles or Scripts folder for the http requests to work.

Answer (score -2):

See this blog post about a simple addition to your project file.
http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx