# sharing views, css, javascript between multiple asp.net mvc 3 projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

It seems to be impossible/hard to share views between several asp.net mvc 3 projects. At least, that's what Google tells me. Please correct me if I am wrong ...

What's about css and js files? Did someone do this already? If so, what is the best practice to achieve this (within a vs studio 2010 solution with several asp.net mvc 3 projects)?

Just curious, is it possible to share css and js between mvc3 areas?

Comment: You could branch/clone from your main version control system repository.

Comment: I use svn. not sure how this would work if the whole solution is in the same repository ...

Comment: Just learning a bit about areas (see for example:http://www.iwantmymvc.com/2011-02-15-mvc-3-areas-and-shared-layouts-part-2) How about areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention svn - it has "svn:externals" property that lets you map a folder (even from a different repository) to a location under the web site root folder. We used it with success to reuse multiple library tools with external resources (scripts, css files, images and views) in a number of MVC applications.

Comment: could you please provide some more details?

Comment: Not really - that's why I asked for more information. To be honest, I am more looking into a portable area solution right now. Not sure whether this will work though so I keep my options open. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. This is about svn:externals - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html . When you have more specific questions - you are welcome to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool way to share js, cshtml, css etc. files using "Add as Link" feature of VS. There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution#answer-8541764) describing the whole process. Also dont forget to [add a build task to copy the files on build](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx) so you'd be able to debug them.