# Including Build action content files directory from referenced assembly at same level as bin directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to copy folder from referenced assembly to same level as bin directory in calling mvc application:

```
MyDLL1
  Shared
     image.png(Build action = content, Copy Always)


MyMvcApp(references MyDLL1)
  Images
  Content
  etc...
  bin
  (shared should be copied here)
```

So if I set up `../` As output path in MyDLL1 setting I am able to get shared folder created in bin directory of MyMvcApp after build,but if I put `../../`, folder doesn't appear anywhere within MyMvcApp directory. Is it possible to get that folder created at same level as bin folder in MyMvcApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed reference to dll since it cointained only static files and added following to postbuild event to MyMvcApp:

```
start xcopy "$(SolutionDir)MyDLL1\Shared\*" "$(SolutionDir)MyMvcApp\Shared" /r /s /i /y
```

- **Start xcopy** - runs xcopy in cmd as admin (solves exit code 4 for me)
- **\*** - copies everything from shared folder
- **/s** - tells it to copy    folders and subfolders
- **/i** - tells it target path is a directory    (otherwise cmd would ask
  you is target path file or directory)
- **/r** -    overwrite readonly files
- **/y** - overwerite files (otherwise cmd would    ask if you want to
  overwrite each file..)