# Add as link intellisense for Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to share some views across projects by using the "Add as Link" feature in VS2015 but the linked view appears broken in VS even though it works fine on the site.

**Is there a way to get features like intellisense and "go to definition" working for a linked View?**

I can reproduce this with a new solution/project:

- Move Home/Index.cshtml to some other folder (currently I'm using a Solution Folder but it doesn't seem to matter where I move the files)
- delete Index.cshtml  from Home/
- from Home/ right click and "add existing item"
- choose Index.cshtml from the Solution Folder but choose "Add as Link" from the button drop down
- on the linked Index.cshtml choose properties "Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always"

The site will work fine but in VS2015 the view then appears broken and no intellisense works.

This would be a great way to share a view across multiple projects but if VS thinks the view is broken it makes developing a pain.

Any suggestions? Is there a better way to share views across projects?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the painful way I got it to work:

1. Unload the solution
2. Create a copy of one of the projects containing the views I want to replicate.  Let's call the new project [**SharedItems**].
3. Rename the `.csproj` file and edit the `.csproj` file manually and replace the old name with the new name (probably optional, but made things easier)
4. Load the solution and add the new project.
5. Delete any files you don't need.
6. Rename the namespaces in the new project.
7. Build just to make sure it's working and Intellisense is working correctly.
8. Delete the files you intend to link in the original projects and create links.
9. Installed the `MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles` NuGet package on all the original projects to automatically make physical copies of the linked files.

Now I can do all my edits in the templated project without having to maintain multiple copies everywhere.

Two big downsides:

- I have to build after making edits to any linked object before I can see the changes.
- I have to open the actual .cshtml files in the [**SharedItems**] project only.  Opening a linked file breaks Intellisense until you close it and open it directly.  This is especially annoying with Resharper's Search Everywhere feature because it suggests linked files.