# How to share CSS file across multiple projects in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio Project Solution which consists of 3 projects. I want the CSS to be shared by these 3 projects in the VS Solution to minimize the changes since all of them are using the same CSS rules.

How can I achieve this? I tried the Add As Link function but the project does not seem to use the linked CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution) gives a very easy step-by-step overview of how to use "Add As Link".

Note that your linked files will not be accessible while debugging your project, unless you add a task to your Project File to manually copy your linked files [as described here](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx).

**Example:**

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles='true' 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true' 
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
</Target>
```