# Share Common Content with multiple Projects

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, tfs, asp.net-mvc-5

Looking for options or even maybe a solution.

I worked for a company that used SubVersion for Source Control and we were able to use 'externals' to drop common content into projects.  This allowed us to drop JS Framework files, custom JS/TS Files, Images, and a standard layout to all the MVC 5 Projects.

I know TFS does not support/use externals and from everything I have read the closest thing is to create a Nuget Package to accomplish this.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution) which is one option.

Comment: NuGet package would be my approach.  What's wrong with that option?

Comment: Nothing other than 1) never built one 2) it doesn't automatically update when it changes