# How can share code/files/folders between projects in same solution using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How can copy all files and folders in 'Folder' from 'ProjectB' to 'ProjectA'

```
Solution
 *ProjectA*

 *ProjectB*
       **Folder**
          SubFolder
             Files.extension
          SubFolder
          SubFolder
          Files.extension
```

In visual studio i have created two different project in same solution. 
I use AngularJS in both of projects, i have create some mine components for management data. Also i use AngularUI routing and i include all components as dependencies.

How can create a copy link for folder 'Folder' from 'ProjectB' that can include in 'ProjectA' ?

For now, i have duplicated all files, so if any change has been place in one project that include 'Folder', i must copy/paste folder 'Folder' to other project, so both projects have same files and code.

**SOLUTION**
In windows you can create linked folder from command prompt with this command 'mklink /D target source'. So any change to one file will bind to other always

Comment: 'Add > Existing Item'. The `Add` button is actually a dropbox button. Select `Add As Link` instead of `Add`

Comment: when i click 'Add > Existing Item', The add button isnot dropdown box, cannot find option Add As Link

Comment: Check again. The `Add` button is a dropdown since 2010 at least, probably a lot earlier. I just don't have a VS 2008 installation anywhere to check. A dropdown button looks like a normal button with a downward-pointing triangle on the right

Comment: And I see that @ShaileshManiyar posted the relevant screenshots too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you share scripts among multiple projects in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution)