# Linked javascript file in Visual Studio 2015 not being included in build/deploy

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I have a bunch of Javascript files in a centralized project in my solution that I would like to share amongst other projects.  However, when building and testing a project with such a linked file, it is 404 when I try to access it in testing my solution.

The script is linked to from the standard Scripts directory in my project - nothing unusual in it's placement.  It doesn't get loaded in my view (`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Models/InteractionDetails.js")`), though the script tag for it does appear in the source and all the other JS files get loaded including a test non-linked js file in the same subdirectory.

How might I get the dratted thing to be properly deployed to the server on build?

This is not a duplicate, as I am using the method outlined to include the files in my project from another project.  The issue is that they are not being used when I build the project (eg, I cannot path to the JS files directly on the server, and they are not included in pages referencing them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you share scripts among multiple projects in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution)

Comment: @Amogh: it is not - I am using that very process, and the problem isn't with the process but with the outcome: the shared files are not being deployed with my project.

Comment: Well in that case, check and set the properties of the linked files correctly. another solution is create post build event.

Comment: "check and set the properties of the linked files correctly" is unfortunately not very helpful.  What would be the "correct" settings n this instance?